# Unity simple solid color alpha shader

Tags: shaders, unity

I searched for a shader, where I can set a solid color, which I can fade in or out like I want. There is not such a thing build in as far as I could see. Now I got this code, which works fine in case of the alpha value, but it turns everything behind upside down. Since I'm absolutely not into shaders, I need help to fix that to a simple alpha shader.

```
Shader "Unity Answers/Solid Transparency Color" 
{ 
    Properties 
    { 
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5) 
    } 

    SubShader 
        { 
            Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent"} 
            ZWrite Off GrabPass { } 
            Pass { Fog { Mode Off } Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

         CGPROGRAM
         #pragma vertex vert
         #pragma fragment frag

         fixed4 _Color;
         sampler2D _GrabTexture;
         struct appdata
         {
             float4 vertex : POSITION;
         };
         struct v2f
         {
             float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
             float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
         };
         v2f vert (appdata v)
         {
             v2f o;
             o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
             o.uv = o.pos;
             return o;
         }
         half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
         {
             float2 coord = 0.5 + 0.5 * i.uv.xy / i.uv.w;
             fixed4 tex = tex2D(_GrabTexture, float2(coord.x, 1 - coord.y));
             return fixed4(lerp(tex.rgb, _Color.rgb, _Color.a), 1);
         }
         ENDCG
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer, with debugging it by myself. The fix is kinda simple, just remove the `1 -`  in this line `fixed4 tex = tex2D(_GrabTexture, float2(coord.x, 1 - coord.y));`

```
Shader "Unity Answers/Solid Transparency Color" 
{ 
    Properties 
    { 
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5) 
    } 

    SubShader 
        { 
            Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent"} 
            ZWrite Off GrabPass { } 
            Pass { Fog { Mode Off } Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

         CGPROGRAM
         #pragma vertex vert
         #pragma fragment frag

         fixed4 _Color;
         sampler2D _GrabTexture;
         struct appdata
         {
             float4 vertex : POSITION;
         };
         struct v2f
         {
             float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
             float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
         };
         v2f vert (appdata v)
         {
             v2f o;
             o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
             o.uv = o.pos;
             return o;
         }
         half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
         {
             float2 coord = 0.5 + 0.5 * i.uv.xy / i.uv.w;
             fixed4 tex = tex2D(_GrabTexture, float2(coord.x, coord.y)); //Here is the fix
             return fixed4(lerp(tex.rgb, _Color.rgb, _Color.a), 1);
         }
         ENDCG
     }
 }
}
```